# System will not boot after sudo update and upgrade on 20.04 kubuntu

Tags: boot, upgrade, login, plasma, sddm

I am using kubuntu and used ubuntu studio add-on to get low latency kernel. After doing a `sudo update and upgrade`, the system stopped booting to the login screen.

I am able to switch to tty2 and login and do a startx. It takes me to a gnome session without my AMD drivers. I have tried to use `systemctrl start sddm` and was not able to get anything to start.

I have not used Linux for about 9 years. Now this is a new journey for me. In the past I would have tried to make a new `xorg.conf` but the ubuntu seams to use a new system for this now and I do not understand how to edit it. I would provide logs bit I dont know what would be safe to post and what would help.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have an update. The first thing i did was back up my home directory using tar. using information i found at https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-home-dir-backup-tar-gpg-guide.html then i wiped and reinstalled. I switched to Ubuntu studio as i am using Bitwig and the KDE plasma version is just great. then uncompressed my home directory back in its place. the next step was to import my Zpool and i was back up and running 80% complete. Still not sure what happened in the first place that messed up my old install. lets hope I'm not missing any thing. thank you!